# Unix - Only list directories which contain a subdirectory

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command

How can I print in the Unix shell the number of directories in a tree which contain other directories?

I haven't found a solution yet with commands like `find` or `ls`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you generate a list of all the directories under a particular directory, and then remove the last component from the name, you have a list of the directories containing subdirectories, but there are likely to be repeats in that list.  So, you need to post-process the list, yielding (as a first approximation):

```
find ${base:-.} -type d |
sed 's%/[^/]*$%%' |
sort -u
```

Find all the directories under the directory or directories listed in variable `$base`, defaulting to the current directory, and print their names.  The code assumes you don't have directories with a newline in the name.  If you do, there are fixes, but the best fix is to rename the directory.  The `sed` command removes the last slash and everything after it.  The sort eliminates duplicate entries.  What's left is the list of directories containing subdirectories.

Well, more or less.  There's the degenerate case to consider: the top-level directories in the list will be listed regardless of whether they have sub-directories or not.  Fixing that is a bit harder.  You need to eliminate any lines of output that exactly match the directories specified to `find` before removing trailing material.  So, you need something like:

```
{
printf '\\#^%s$#d\n' ${base:-.}
echo 's%/[^/]*$%%'
} > sed.script
find ${base:-.} -type d |
sed -f sed.script |
sort -u
rm -f sed.script
```

The `\\#^%s$#d` assumes you don't use `#` in directory names.  If you do use it, then you need to find a character you don't use in names (maybe Control-A) and use that in place of the `#`.  If you could face absolutely any character, then you'll need to do more work escaping some obscure character, such as Control-A, when it appears in a directory name.

There's a problem still: using a fixed name like `sed.script` for a temporary file name is bad (for multiple reasons — such as two people trying to run the script at the same time in the same directory, though it can also be a security risk), so use `mktemp` to create a temporary file name:

```
tmp=$(mktemp ${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/dircnt.XXXXXX)
trap "rm -f $tmp; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15
{
printf '\\#^%s$#d\n' ${base:-.}
echo 's%/[^/]*$%%'
} > $tmp
find ${base:-.} -type d |
sed -f $tmp |
sort -u
rm -f $tmp
trap 0
```

This deals with the most common signals (HUP, INT, QUIT, PIPE, TERM) and removes the temporary file even if one of those arrives.

Clearly, if you want to simply count the number of directories, you can pipe the output from the commands above through `wc -l` to get the count.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find` command: `find . -type d -not -empty`

That will print every subdirectory that is not empty. You can control how deep you want the search with `-maxdepth`.

To print the number, you can use `wc -l`.

```
find . -type d -not -empty | wc -l
```

Comment: Does [`-empty`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Size) do what's needed?  It looks for files in a directory; a directory with a file is not empty, even though it contains no subdirectory.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler good point, it works for directories too according to the man pages and with `-type d` we specify to just look at dirs.

Comment: Thank you! Now i like to count how many of these subdirectories are also containing
directories. This is what i got so far:

'find -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2'

But it happens, that a subdirectory contains more than one directory, so it's listed more than one time. I only want to check if it's got one or more and then “add” to my list, instead off add is every time i find a directory in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1d */*/. | cut -d / -f1 | uniq
```